# Question regarding Java producer-consumer scenario

Tags: java, synchronization, producer-consumer

I know similar questions have been asked bunch of times, but I spent some time reading similar questions and couldn't find a proper answer.

Here's the code:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Message message = new Message();
    (new Thread(new Writer(message))).start();
    (new Thread(new Reader(message))).start();
  }
}

class Message {
  private String message;
  private boolean empty = true;
  
  public synchronized String read() {
    while(empty) {
      try {
        System.out.println("Reader is waiting...relinquish the lock");
        wait();
      } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }
    empty = true;
    notifyAll();
    return message;
  }
  
  public synchronized void write(String message) {
    while(!empty) {
      try {
        System.out.println("Writer is waiting...relinquish the lock");
        wait();
      } catch(InterupptedException e) {
      }
    }
    empty = false;
    this.message = message;
    notifyAll();
  }
}


class Writer implements Runnable {
  private Message message;
  
  public Writer(Message message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public void run() {
    String messages[] = {
      // some message here
    };
    for(int i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
      message.write(messages[i]);
    }
    message.write("Finished");
  }
}


class Reader implements Runnable {
  private Message message;
  
  public Reader(Message message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public void run() {
    for(String msg = message.read(); !msg.equals("Finished"); msg = message.read()) {
      System.out.println(msg);
  }
}
```

My understanding is, after a single read() method returns in the Reader thread's for loop, the flag empty changed to true, Writer thread gets woken up by the notifyAll() and ready to be scheduled to run, but the Reader has yet to relinquish the lock on Message object, which means Writer cannot call synchronized write() method because it is still blocked. Then Reader thread should call read() again, enters the while loop, prints out the "Reader is waiting..." message and then call wait() to relinquish the lock, so that Writer thread can go on and acquire the lock and call write() method.

But from the output message shown in the console, a lot of times "Reader is waiting..." message didn't get printed at all, only a few times it did. From the above reasoning, shouldn't this message get printed each and every time the program is run?

Comment: So it seems I missed the point that a Thread would relinquish the lock by either calling wait() OR LEAVING MONITOR. When Reader's read() method returns it relinquishes the lock on message object, thus it is not necessary for the Writer thread to wait until Reader thread to call wait() in the next iteration. I thought the only way for a thread to relinquish lock is by calling wait(), apparently i was wrong.